# NSIS failing to run driver installer batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation, driver, nsis

**UPDATE: Everyone struggling to use an NSI installer to install an INF file look no further. This actually works.**

I have made a batch file that successfully installs a device driver in administrator mode. If I copy this into C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\Driver along with the driver it can successfully execute and install the driver.

However, when I attempt to call this **exact** batch file from an NSIS installer using ExecWait it doesn't run the batch file. The files are coped into the **exact** location as mentioned above.

How on earth do you successfully call a batch file from a NSIS file?

**Relevant snippet from NSIS:**

```
# Installer sections
Section -Main SEC0000

    # Copy viewer software to PC
    SetOverwrite on

       #(software stuff) ...

    # Copy USB slave driver to PC
    SetOutPath $TEMP\Driver
    File ..\Driver\c500.cat
    File ..\Driver\c500.inf
    File ..\Driver\runme.bat
    File ..\Driver\install.bat

    # Remove the Windows 7/8/10 magic relocated ini file (if it exists)
    Delete /REBOOTOK "$LOCALAPPDATA\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\CompanyName\C500-510\C500_510.ini"

    WriteRegStr HKLM "${REGKEY}\Components" Main 1
SectionEnd

# Install C500 USB slave driver
Section -InstallDriver SEC0001
    SetOverwrite on
    DetailPrint "Install C500 USB slave driver"

    # Install USB slave driver if desired
    ${If} ${Cmd} `MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "Install C500 USB slave driver?" IDYES`
        ExecWait "$TEMP\Driver\runme.cmd"
    ${EndIf}

    WriteRegStr HKLM "${REGKEY}\Components" InstallDriver 1
SectionEnd
```

**install.bat**

```
set fn=%~dp0c500.inf
echo fn is %fn%
::cd %windir% && %windir%\system32\pnputil.exe -i -a %~dp0\c500.inf
cd %windir%
echo %cd%
pnputil -i -a %fn%
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto success
echo Device installation failed.
echo Try to run install.bat as Administrator
echo Or check if your system has the usbser.sys file
goto end
:success
echo Device installation completed.
:end
pause
```

**runme.bat**

```
@echo off

powershell -Command "Start-Process 'install.bat' -ArgumentList  '%~dp0\c500.inf' -Verb runAs"
```

Update: 
If I change ".cmd" in the NSIS file to ".bat" I get cmd windows with the following errors.

[image]

Comment: This might be a long shot, but give it a try just in case... So for the  `runme.bat` script use this . . . **`1.`** add `SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` on one line,**`2.`** then add `CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"` on the line beneath that, and then finally on the line beneath that add **`3.`** `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& Start-Process 'install.bat' -ArgumentList '%~dp0\c500.inf'"` so in place of what you have, use that instead. Let me know how testing goes for you and whether or not that helps and I'll add an answer if so and you want me to.

Comment: No luck. Remember that I have no issues when running runme.bat directly. I really think the issue lies within the nsis file. I've tried so many ways to call the runme.bat file but it just never opens the command window, yet completes the installer as though it worked just fine.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that I can run the runme.bat file from AppData/Temp prove this is ok? I definitely can't directly run the .bat file from ProgramFiles but I can from here. By the way I'll add more detail to the question now. Alas I tried and $DESKTOP didn't help.

Comment: Okay, well try putting the line `CD /D "C:\WINDOWS\System32"` just above the line of `pnputil -i -a %fn%` in the `install.bat` file. Let me know if this helps any.

Comment: nope :( :( :( :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pnputil.exe only exists in the [64-bit system32 folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955767.aspx).

You can disable the filesystem redirection applied to 32-bit apps:

```
RequestExecutionLevel Admin

!include x64.nsh

Section
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
nsExec::ExecToLog '"$WINDIR\system32\PnPutil.exe" -i -a "$TEMP\Driver\c500.inf"' 
Pop $0
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
DetailPrint $0
SectionEnd
```

Comment: My test machine is 64 bit win10

Comment: You can try executing the batch file with nsExec.

Comment: Your suggestion worked in Windows 10. After everything I've tried I am in shock.

Comment: This failed in windows 7 32bit and 64bit and windows 8.1 64 bit. Invalid INF passed as parameter. These versions of windows aren't activated. Will re-try after activation.

Comment: It still has the same issue with activated Win7 64. Any ideas? Clearly my INF file is fine.

Comment: Did you try executing the batchfile with redirection turned off?

Comment: No, I figured your code made my batch files redundant as their only real benefit was prompting the user for administrator rights. I'll try it now though.

Comment: Someone with a similar problem @ http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=353841 are doing it without a batch file but they are using cmd.exe for some reason.